# Meaning of the bold line in Peskin and Schroeder's Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, notation, feynman-diagrams

I'm studying chapter 6 of Peskin and Schroeder, on page 185, Peskin and Schroeder mysteriously used bold lines for the incoming and outgoing fermions $k$ and $k'$ but not $p$ or $p'$;

[image]

The same bold line also occurs previously multiple times, e.g. at the very beginning of chapter 6

[image]

Anyone knows why they used bold lines here?

Comment: As stated in the text, it just stands for some heavy particle, heavy enough so that you don't have to worry about what it's doing (it just sits there).

Comment: This is related to @knzhou's comment, but often people use that sort of heavy line to represent a classical external source. (It's related to knzhou's comment in the sense that a heavy, stable particle that acts as a source/sink of momentum is a lot like a classical source.) That's not what P&S mean, but that might also give you another piece of intuition / context.